# how can we hard-code profiles into the code to unlock a record in a VF page

Tags: visualforce

We have a `Visualforce Page` where if all the details are filled and submitted for approval, then the record is locked. But I want a few profiles to be able to edit the locked record and make changes. How can I achieve this in code?

Comment: If you give those profile ModifyAll privileges then they can edit the record even if it is locked. (Depending on how you locked it)

Comment: The record is locked with code in the VF page

Comment: Ok, then you will have to alter the code to allow the profiles to edit it. A custom setting would be a good choice to identify the profile either by name or ID

Answer (score 1):

It's best to work with the platform where possible. Create a **custom permission** to control edit access once locked. Then assign the permission to the appropriate users either via profiles or a permission set.

Beware if you go down the route of creating a list of approved profiles, either by Name or ID. Profile names vary depending on the user's selected language - so your code allow people with the profile **System Administrator** to make changes, but block access when their profile is **Administrateur système**.

And in both cases, your hard-coded list will be unaware of new profiles created by the user.